# jQuery html() method unbinding events to elements inside the inner html after swapping?

Tags: jquery, html, events, click

I ran into an interesting problem. On my site, i swap out content dynamically when hovering over a certain link. This is accomplished by something similar to:

```
$('#box').html($('#newcontent').html());
```

Now inside this `#newcontent` part, there is a `<button>`-Element to which I assigned a click event like this: (inside the `$(document).ready()`-function)

```
$("button#buttonName").click(function(){
  $("div#containerName").toggleClass("hidden");
  }
```

`hidden` is a css-Class doing the display:none magic. The container `#containerName` is **outside** both the element containing the button and the element containing the structure that is being changed with `html()`.

Mockup of the structure at this point

```
<div id="somethingthatwhenhoveredoverwillswapthecontent">Hover over me!</div>

<div id="box">Change me!</div>

<div id="newcontent" class="hidden">I am renewed!
  <button id="buttonName">Show the weird box at the bottom</button>
</div>

<div id="containerName" class="hidden">
  I am content that is only shown when the button is clicked
</div>
```

So what happens is this: the page is loaded, the content swapping script works fine, but the button will not fire it's click event, which for testing reasons didn't even give an `alert('whatever');`. It looks like once the html() swaps the content from the `<div id="newcontent">` to the `<div id="box">`, **the event gets unbound** (I suspect).

Is this just me not grasping a concept or is the whole approach done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behind the scenes jQuery is creating a new DOM element, rather than making a 'copy' of the original. Because of this it doesn't have the event handler of the original. You can either manually re-assign the handlers along with your `html()` call, or you can use `delegate()` to add the event, like this:

```
$("#box").delegate("#buttonName", 'click', function(){
    $("#containerName").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: Dear Rory, thank you very much for the explanation and the example. As you can imagine, it instantly solved my problem. Time for me to read up on delegates I would say :)